# Sorting Cell Array

Tags: matlab, sorting, cell

I have a cell array that I want to sort based on a column. However, MATLAB is telling me `sortrows` doesn't work for cell arrays. I saw on some of the other questions that it does work, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The cell array I'm looking at is called PM25. It's a 1x7 cell. Each of the 7 PM25{i}'s are of the form 365x5xnumber in which the number varies.

Here's a link to the .mat file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/li3hh1nvt11vok5/4YGfwStQlo
It's the PM25 variable.

I basically want to get into the 365x5xnumber level and sort each of those according to column 5.

Here's what I have been doing. I converted to double because that's the only way MATLAB would let me do sortrows, but I'd rather not because I lose some of the information in my date and name columns. When I left it in cell form, MATLAB would tell me either cells didn't work with sortrows or that I didn't make the data a 2-D matrix.

```
for i = 1:length(names) % 7 states
    for j = 1:length(PM25{i}(1,1,:)) % length of each of the `numbers` - Number of sites
        PM25_info = str2double(PM25{i});
        PM25_sorted = sortrows(PM25_info(:,:,j),5);  
    end
end
```

The code above doesn't generate an error, but it still doesn't sort the 5th column. I don't know what is wrong.

The ideal thing would be to leave PM25 as a cell and sort.

Comment: Actually, try: sortrows(PM25_info{:,:,j},5)

Comment: Try it where? PM25_info was converted to a double. It's no longer a cell

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you were trying without converting, but I tried the code below and it seemed to work the way you want it too.  It didn't appear to lose any information either. I hope this works out for you.

```
%Getting 7 random matrices 365x5xnumber
a = rand(365,5,floor(rand(1).*8)+1).*10;
b = rand(365,5,floor(rand(1).*8)+1).*10;
c = rand(365,5,floor(rand(1).*8)+1).*10;
d = rand(365,5,floor(rand(1).*8)+1).*10;
e = rand(365,5,floor(rand(1).*8)+1).*10;
f = rand(365,5,floor(rand(1).*8)+1).*10;
g = rand(365,5,floor(rand(1).*8)+1).*10;

%put in cell array
PM25 = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g};

for i = 1:length(PM25)%7 states
    for j = 1:length(PM25{i}(1,1,:))%length of numbers
        PM25_sort{i}(:,:,j) = sortrows(PM25{i}(:,:,j),5);
    end
end
```

Comment: I get this error:`Some cells in X contain non-scalar values and cannot be sorted.` I think it might be because some of my columns are not numbers - I have a column of dates (in the form [733138], [733139] etc) and a column of siteID's in the form '19-001-0007'.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cellfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
%Creating an example cell array
a=cell(1,7);
for i=1:7
   a{i}=rand(365,5,randi(10));
end
result=cellfun(@(x) sort(x,2),a,'UniformOutput',false);
```

`result` will be a `1x7` cell array in which each matrix will be sorted with respect to the second dimension.

Comment: Your code works fine for the cell you made and the cells are the right size, but I'm getting this error: `Error using sort
DIM and MODE arguments not supported for cell arrays.` I added a link above to my file - could you try it with that? I don't know if the issue is that some of my columns are not just numbers.

Comment: I saw your data. In each cell, you have 4th and 5th column where you have cells of single elements. First convert them to double.

Comment: How can I maybe keep track of the indexing? I need the data in those columns and converting to double makes them NaN. So I at least need to be able to know which values they were before.

Comment: how are you converting to `double`? You should do `cell2mat`

Comment: I tried this: `date = cell2mat(PM25{i}(:,4,j))`, which turns the string into double. But then I can't place the double back into the PM25 (`PM25{i}(:,4,j) = date;`) because `Conversion from cell to double is not possible`. Do you know how I can do that?